# Types that constrain vectors based on norm

Tags: haskell, math, functional-programming, agda, idris

In a language like Haskell or Idris, is it possible to create a data type which checks if an input vector for a function is, for instance, unitary?  That is, can I create a data type SumsToOne which checks if a vector adds up to 1, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In Idris it's kind of just as you say. You could wrap a list with a proof the elements sum to one

```
data SumsToOne : Type where
  STO : (xs : List Int) -> {auto prf : sum xs = 1} -> SumsToOne
```

Though if by data type you are referring to the proof, rather than the elements as well, you can just

```
go : (xs : List Int) -> {auto prf : sum xs = 1} -> <whatever you're returning>
```

The proof is of type `sums xs = 1`. `prf` is just the function parameter name, and  `auto` means Idris will find the proof for you if it can.

I don't know if this will work for floating point elements.